# How to use WEKA source code in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, weka

i started coding for WEKA with including weka.jar in my project. But now I need to change some parts in the WEKA source code. That means that I have to add the source code as new project in my eclipse evironment i guess.

I did that with the WEKA SVN and it appered as new project. But now I have no idea how to handle it. How can I replace the WEKA.jar with the source code, so that everything still works but I can make some changes?

Thank your very much!

2081105

Comment: Generate a new JAR from the WEKA source code.

Comment: Thanks; but isn't there a way to use it as code? So I would be faster

Comment: You can use Ant to automatically generate the JAR for you. You can alternatively add the WEKA project to the build path of your project. Don't forget to remove the old WEKA JAR from the build path.

Answer (score 0):

I tried in netbeans and it's very easy ,just 4 steps

1. Download Weka Source Code 
   svn checkout https://svn.cms.waikato.ac.nz/svn/weka/tags/dev-3-5-8/weka
2. You can directly open that project in Netbeans
3. Build project
4. Run -> weka.gui.GUIChooser